# Duplicate content with forwarding from TLD to different 'start page'

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I came across something interesting today.

See [this site](http://www.alclawyers.com.au).

Notice that the TLD automatically forwards to /about-alc/. This is because, the home section is actually called 'About ALC'.

I recently used a [site map generator](http://sitemapdoc.com), and it said 'Duplicate content' for the TLD and the /about-alc/

Is this not a good approach? Should I just throw a canonical meta tag in there and that will be enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical tags are the way to go if you insist on remain redirecting to that subpage. I'd rather use a different start site under /, just to be able to pack more keyword-laden text into the site.